# How do I reduce the desktop icon size in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, icons

How can I reduce the size of my desktop icons if the video resolution is already on the highest setting?

Comment: This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/47596/221041) allows to change icon size, horizontal and veritcal spacing, without rebooting!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you click a blank bit of the desktop, hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and scroll down using the mouse wheel, you can scale down the desktop icons until they're almost non-existent.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + *scroll wheel* works to zoom in most applications (browser, MS Office, Windows Explorer, etc.).

Comment: Works on Vista too

Comment: What if you have a busted mouse wheel like mine? It is very hard to control precisely. I wish there was a keyboard combination

Answer (score 56):

Right click the desktop > View > Small Icons (Classic on Vista). That is the smallest icon size you can have.

[image]

If these sizes are still not small (or big) enough for you, then you can hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> whilst scrolling the Scroll Wheel to change it to the exact size you want.

Comment: Ctrl + mouse wheel is great

Comment: Best answer - doesn't the mouse wheel just control the zoom? Pretty sure mine was on the smallest zoom already (default).

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this but I would've thought this was a registry setting, according to google it is :)

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
"Shell Icon Size"="36"
```

The value '36' is the default (medium size) if I'm correct, a smaller value means smaller icons.

*Note: Fiddling with the registry can be dangerous so only use this if the default 'small/medium/large/extra large' don't suffice.*

Comment: I have tested this and there was no influence on the desktop icons size (though I did not attempt to restart).