# How can I change the desktop icon size in Windows 7 without the mouse wheel?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-icons

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How do I reduce the desktop icon size in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/11922/how-do-i-reduce-the-desktop-icon-size-in-windows-7)

In Windows 7, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + the mouse wheel to change your icon size on your desktop.

How do you do this on a laptop without any scroll wheel?

Comment: You can also use a program like AutoHotkey to create a hotkey that simulates the mouse scroll-wheel (for example, `Ctrl+Alt+Up` = `WheelUp`/`Ctrl+Alt+Down` = `WheelDown`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still do it through the right click menu, but you can only pick from three choices instead of the many in-between options:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Sucks that you are limited to those choices without the mouse wheel.

Answer (score 9):

Right click on an empty part of the desktop, and then choose the **Personalize** command from the shortcut menu. When the Personalization window appears, click the **Window Color** icon.

This will open the **Windows Color and Appearance** dialog box.

From the **Item** drop-down menu select **Icon**.

[image]

Now you can adjust the icon size exactly to your likings and apply the new settings.

It is far more customizable than just the three options from the **View** menu. You can also adjust the horizontal and vertical icon spacing there.

Comment: Wonderful, it allows to change icon size, horizontal and veritcal spacing, without rebooting!

Answer (score 3):

Start menu → *Run* → *regedit*.

Find the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
```

Modify "*Shell Icon Size*". The smaller the number, the smaller the icons. You'll have to reboot to see the effect.

Answer (score 2):

Technically this is not the exact answer to your question but if you want to reduce the size of desktop icons, you can try the following: Most laptops allow treating simultaneous click of left and right mouse buttons as a middle click. On my laptop, I was able to use this feature to resize the icons on the desktop. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left + right + trackpad scroll up/down).