# How can I control the size of desktop icons on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reduce the desktop icon size in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/11922/how-do-i-reduce-the-desktop-icon-size-in-windows-7)

I’ve got Windows 7 running in a virtual machine for testing websites. I’ve got several user accounts for [testing in different versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785991/can-i-run-multiple-versions-of-google-chrome-on-the-same-machine-mac-or-windows/3786165#3786165).

In one of those user accounts, the desktop icons have gotten much bigger than usual.

I must be being a bit stupid, but I can’t find out how to change them back for the life of me. Where is the option to do this?

Comment: Aha, here we go:

http://superuser.com/questions/47590/how-to-change-desktop-icon-size-in-windows-7-without-mouse-wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right click on the desktop and choose "View" -> "Medium Icons" to return to the normal sized icons.

Answer (score 2):

One of the easyest ways is just hold CTRL keyboard buttom and wheel up or down the [scrool wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_wheel) on the center of your mouse under your mouse poiter is on somewhere on your desktop backgruound or on some icon. This will allow you to increase or decrease your desktop icons size.

Comment: And why didn't I know about this till now. Thanks!

Comment: Good shout. Unfortunately, I can’t do that until I hunt down a mouse, as I’m running Windows 7 in a virtual machine on a Mac OS X laptop, and doing the CTRL+trackpad up/down move causes Mac OS X to zoom in, rather than Windows. I’ll see if I can find a scrollwheel mouse though, if there isn’t another way to change the icon size.

Comment: Maybe you can acess your VM using mstsc(Remote Desdktop Protocol), if you can do it im certain that you can resize your icons using this shortcut.

Comment: @Diogo: any idea what the long cut is? I’m not sure I want to muck around with Remote Desktops.

Comment: try CTRL-VMCTRLBUtton-Trackpad up/down  in the case of say vmware thats alt.