# How to lengthen the displayed folder name in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, filenames, text-formatting

This isn't really a big issue, but just because I am being particular about it.
Some folder names will get cut off in the middle of the word.

[image]

Is there a setting or way, even something hackish, to extend the max wrap around length of folder or file names? 
Limiting the wrap around to only non-alphanumeric characters would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the [advanced Appearance Setting dialog](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2422164/en-us):

[image]

Here increase the horizontal spacing to a higher values until it matches your longer string.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The displayed text field space is determined by the Icon size.  It's wrapped at the width of the Icon.

Perhaps check out "[How to change desktop icon size in Windows 7 without mouse wheel?](https://superuser.com/questions/47590/how-to-change-desktop-icon-size-in-windows-7-without-mouse-wheel)" and/or "[How do I reduce the desktop icon size in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/11922/how-do-i-reduce-the-desktop-icon-size-in-windows-7)" for some ideas on how ot adjust the icon size.

Comment: It does work, but I do not want to resize my icons. :[